# Working With Designers/Content Writers

Tags: gui-design, workflow, team-building

I am a server side programmer who as of the last year has really had to get comfortable with front end design and UX. I feel that I am currently producing good experience for the user however I lack any artistic ability. At my work we are currently trying to integrate with an existing Marking service who has mainly done Print work.

Does anyone here have experience working with other teams to put a website together. Unfortunately we don't have the budget to hire a front end designer so I am seeking out any materials or experience you guys may have had working with other teams. And any big pitfalls you have run into.

Very sorry if this is the wrong place to ask I could not think of another one though and really want this from a developer point of view than a managerial one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come from an academic design and communications background and through 15 years of professional design experience – with the last 4 years as a dedicated software product/UX designer – have overcome many of the challenges you will experience using a print designer as a software visual designer.

First of all I'd state that not all designers are the same. Most are creative and to be creative, you have to put some of yourself into each and every design you do. This often makes it difficult to remain objective and create *User centric* solutions, rather than aesthetic solutions.

That was the biggest learning curve I made transitioning. Design choices based on science, research and testing, rather than aesthetics.

Aesthetics play a huge role, but at the right time and in the right way. Design embellishment for the sake of it has little place in the world of interface design.

Visual design helps by guiding users around functionality, pulls the eye in the right directions, accents hierarchy, aids in intuitiveness and the age old 'don't make me think' philosophy. It also has a huge effect on the perception of quality which aids in accelerating opportunities through the sales cycle.

The transition can be done. I have known a few designers that have done it very well and you get a far more rounded UX professional at the end of it. But it takes time, and I know many designers that are incredibly creative but simply don't have the analytical skills to successfully make the transition.

The short version of the answer is that there is no short-cut, follow the process, for example;

Market requirements > conceptual wireframes > validation (internal)  > iterate > validation (market) > iterate > visual design > validation > agile development (scrum, user stories, sprints).

This is just an example process, but the point is there ***is*** a process, and by following a conceptualizing and validation process that works for your organization you will help a new designer, with the right skill set, ultimately become successful in his/her transition from print to UX.

There are hundreds of resource out there, but the first one that set me on the ***right*** path was; Designing for the Digital Age, by Kim Goodwin.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This book is just what I was looking for. Looks like I am going to have to do a lot of reading over this weekend.